# sendmail smtp auth simple,why fail auth?

Tags: sendmail, smtp, sasl

On sendmail i did this for smtp auth
sasl is running

```
root      1609     1  0 05:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root      1610  1609  0 05:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root      1611  1609  0 05:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root      1612  1609  0 05:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 5
root      1613  1609  0 05:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/saslauthd -a pam -c -m /var/run/saslauthd -n 5
```

Sasl sendmail is configured
(/usr/lib/sasl2/sendmail.conf)

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: LOGIN PLAIN
```

I have configured sendmail smtp as this

```
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5')dnl
```

Of course i have compiled the file and restart sendmail
smtp auth seems to be working(telnet localhost)

```
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 2097152
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
```

When i do,auth login ask for base64 encoded user
i put it,then password,and i put it
And give

```
535 5.7.0 authentication failed
```

for convert to base64 i use this script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use MIME::Base64;
print encode_base64("$ARGV[0]");
exit 0;
```

Of course saslpasswd2 user was given first
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/257275/sendmail-sasl2-auth-error)

Instead of use -a pam for saslauthd use -a sasldb
like this

```
saslauthd  -a sasldb
```